Library not loaded: @rpath/libarchive.20.dylib on M2 macOs
I get this error while i'm trying to install libarrow
While installing the red-arrow gem (v17.0.0) this command failed conda install -c conda-forge -y libarrow
also i get the same error for conda install conda-forge::libmamba
Error while loading conda entry point: conda-libmamba-solver (dlopen(/Users/zsg/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/libmambapy/bindings.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: @rpath/libarchive.20.dylib
  Referenced from: <496442DC-0EDE-3705-A2B5-401A4FC0D733> /Users/zsg/miniconda3/lib/libmamba.2.0.0.dylib
  Reason: tried: '/Users/zsg/miniconda3/lib/libarchive.20.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/zsg/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/libmambapy/../../../libarchive.20.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/zsg/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/libmambapy/../../../libarchive.20.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/zsg/miniconda3/bin/../lib/libarchive.20.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/zsg/miniconda3/bin/../lib/libarchive.20.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libarchive.20.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libarchive.20.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache))

CondaValueError: You have chosen a non-default solver backend (libmamba) but it was not recognized. Choose one of: classic

how can i solve this? please help.

In my case(macOS arm64) I download the Mambaforge bash and execute it works for me:
wget https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/download/24.7.1-2/Mambaforge-24.7.1-2-MacOSX-arm64.sh && bash Mambaforge-24.7.1-2-MacOSX-arm64.sh


I ended up reinstalling conda and the problem was solved.
curl -L -O "https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/latest/download/Miniforge3-$(uname)-$(uname
-m).sh" bash Miniforge3-$(uname)-$(uname -m).sh

source https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge
